# Efficiently replace text data in columns

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to clean up an excel file, that is an export of a Sharepoint list. I'm trying to consolidate text data in the columns using the following:

```
df = df.replace({'Advisor' : { }})
```

While this works very well, this excel file has tracked data for several years now. So for column `Advisor` there has been a lot of turn-over in staff. Typical entries in this column will be: `Person A; Person B; Person C`. So in this case, if `Person C` is still employed, I would run:

`df. df.replace('Advisor' : {"Person A; Person B; Person C" : "Person C"}})`

That's all well and good, but as you can imagine there are many permutations, and it's time consuming to type out all of the dictionary combos.

Is there a way to incorporate an `if` function such that if `Person C` is present in the cell, then clean up the entry and refer to `Person C` only.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Contains**

Find all occurrences of 'Person C' with `df['Advisor'].str.contains('Person C')` and replace them.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Advisor': ['Person A; Person B; Person C',
                               'Person A; Person C',
                               'Person A; Person B', ]})

df['New'] = df['Advisor']

df.loc[ df['New'].str.contains('Person C'), 'New' ] = 'Person C'
```

```
                        Advisor                 New
0  Person A; Person B; Person C            Person C
1            Person A; Person C            Person C
2            Person A; Person B  Person A; Person B
```

To make it case insensitive use `case=False`

```
df.loc[ df['New'].str.contains('Person C', case=False), 'New' ] = 'Person C'
```

**Option 2: Regex Replace**

Use regular expressions to find all cells that contain "Person C" instances and replace them.

```
df['New'] = df['New'].replace('.*Person C.*', 'Person C', regex=True)
```

Explanation:

- The `.*` matches any character, therefore, any name before and after "Person C"
- `regex=True` enables regex matching